# Изучаю OpenGL4, что такое шейдеры? Есть пара вопросов

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, шейдеры

Я начал учить OpenGL4, по этому сайту.
http://opengl-tutorial.blogspot.com/p/2.html?m=1
И в уроке что по ссылке, разбирают рисование треугольника и придание цвета через шейдер! На другом языке от OpenGL... GLSL
Правильно ли я понял, что то, что прописано в шейдере, будет выполняться на GPU?

И почему надо делать через шейдер?

Ведь можно задать цвет через `glColor3f`. Или это будет не правильно?

Анимацию тоже надо делать через шейдер? если я буду задавать треугольнику смещение по оси x не через GLSL. То это все будет хорошо работать через CPU?

Короче через шейдеры я напрямую могу работать с видео картой?

Comment: да, шейдер это программа для gpu, если Вы хотите поменять цвет или подвинуть треугольник - можно шейдеры не использовать, но в примере они есть, чтобы показать "пайплайн" чуть больше чем без шейдеров

Comment: а не на всех видеократах можно просто так без шейдеров.

Comment: полагаю на всех, шейдеры появились позже, однако сейчас почти всегда используются именно они, как более продвинутый и гибкий вариант.. по крайней мере я не знаю где нельзя

Comment: вроде на амд картах если забыть добавить шейдер, то ничего не увидишь. На нвидиа, если забыть добавить шейдер, то скорее всего треугольники будут белые.

Comment: Спасибо за прояснения. Но я немного недопонял. То есть я могу с помощью шейдеров делать и вычисления? Допустим написать физику для игры? И это все будет выполнятся на gpu? Иначе будет все будет на cpu?

Comment: программист выбирает что и где посчитать, у гпу другая архитектура нежели на цпу, не все алгоритмы можно распараллелить

Comment: первоначально шейдеры использовались для того отчего у них такое название - для подсчета освещения и затенения, в 2020 на шейдерах что-только не считают и каких только техник их использования не придумали

Comment: например вот это - одна большая формула https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3lsSzf

Comment: А что значит распараллелить? Правильно ли я понял что  в основном у gpu идёт многопоточная работа?

Comment: Скажем так, упрощаю для лучшего понимания, для того чтобы нарисовать треугольник при помощи шейдеров будет использовано 3+n вычислительных ядер работающих независимо друг от друга. 3 ядра будут считать программу вешинного шейдера (3 т.к. треугольник задается 3мя точками-вершинами) и n фрагментных, n - кол-во пикселей на экране, которые занимает получившийся треугольник. Вершинный шейдер на выходе дает положение одной вершины, фрагментный - цвет одного пикселя. Каждая стадия вычисляется параллельно, без возможности синхронизации между ядрами

Comment: То есть как я понял, если будет 3д модель с наличием 1000вершин, то будет задействовано 1000 ядер?

Comment: бог с ними с вершинами,  на fullhd мониторе 2073600 пикселей...

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок и разбейте вопрос на несколько -- слишком много вопросов в одном